# Trim specific chars, but only if they are at the start or end of the variable

Tags: bash

Say I have a variable set like this:

```
basePath="/some/path/"
```

I need to trim this such that it will result as `"some/path"`.

But I need it to result as `"some/path"` if it is set like any of these:

```
basePath="/some/path"

basePath="some/path/"

basePath="some/path"
```

In C# this is a fairly easy task.  It has a built in trim function that can take care of this for me.

In Bash I am seeing examples that assume you know if the leading and trailing chars are there.  I am trying to sanitize some input, so I don't really know if the leading or trailing slashes are there.

**How can I trim off the leading and trailing forward slashes if they are there, but not trim any other chars?**

Answer (score 5):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
basePath=${basePath#/} # removes a leading `/` if it is there
basePath=${basePath%/} # removes a trailing `/` if it is there
```

Example usage

```
for basePath in /some/path some/path/ some/path; do
    basePath=${basePath#/}
    basePath=${basePath%/}
    echo "$basePath"
done
```

prints

```
some/path
some/path
some/path
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` seems to be a better option than parameter expansion for this case since you can do substitutions in one line only:

```sh
basePath="$(sed 's#^/\?##;s#/\?$##g' <<< "$basePath")"
```

Comment: downside is you incur the overhead of spawning a subprocess; 2 parameter expansions are going to be a lot faster than invoking a subprocess

Answer (score 1):

Removes leading or trailing slash

```
echo ${basePath} | sed 's@^/@@; s@/$@@'
```

Answer (score 1):

This sed` can do this in a single step:

```sh
sed -E 's~^/|/$~~g' <<< "$basePath"
```

This matches a `/` at the start or end and replaces with an empty string.

**Demo:**

```sh
cat file

/some/path
some/path/
some/path
/some/path/

sed -E 's~^/|/$~~g' file

some/path
some/path
some/path
some/path
```